# Angular 6: Navigate to Anchor in the same page

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-router

I am building a Web app in Angular 6 which lists several components that should looks like this:
[image]

Each section should be a component. And the navigation should just scroll to the anchor in the page. It is not accepted to use ids as target of the anchor.

I did this:

**HTML**

```
      <div class="sidebar" padding>
          <ion-title>{{ section.components }}</ion-title>
          <ion-list *ngFor="let index of section.componentsIndex">
            <a [routerLink]="['']" fragment="{{ index[1] }}">
              <ion-item lines="none">{{ index[0] }}</ion-item>
            </a>
          </ion-list>
...
      </div>
      <div class="containers">
        <doc-table href="#table"></doc-table>
        <doc-tabs href="#tabs"></doc-tabs>
        <doc-textarea href="#textarea"></doc-textarea>
        <doc-textinput href="#textinput"></doc-textinput>
      </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I imported the AppRoutingModule in my **app.component.ts** and the routing module looks like this:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppWrapperComponent },
  { path: 'footer', component: FooterComponent },
```

...
    ];

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    useHash: false,
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    scrollOffset: [0, 50]
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The routing is building itself as expected. When I hover over a link in the menu I get for example this: **localhost:4200/#tabs**

Everything lokks like in the book, however the links does not scroll to the position of the component.

I have been since two days reading a lot of stuff, tutorials, Angular documentation, lot of posts here in Stackoverflow and so on. But without success.

I do not get any error.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will b e appreciated